# jquery functions inside of dynamically generated html not working

Tags: jquery, html

I looked up the load method to find an alternative to php includes. I got the load to add html dynamically and it works. The one issue though is that function aren't working. I think it's either an order issue, structure issue or plain logic. Any help to get my functions to work in dynamically generated html would be greatly appreciated. Sample structure below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    $("header").load("/_includes/header.html");

});

$(window).bind("load", function () {
    "use strict";

    $('.class').click(function () {
        $('#id').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: I have the impression that you will have to use `delegated events` here...

Comment: Im sorry I do not understand.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `.class` element defined inside `header.html` then you need to use <kbd>**[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**</kbd> as below:

```
$(document).on('click','.class',function () {
        $('#id').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

> **Event delegation** should be used on controls which are added to `DOM` at later part or after `DOM` gets loaded.

---

**UPDATE**

When you attach event directly to element like below:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
....
});
```

or as below:

```
$('.element').on('click',function(){
....
});
```

those event will not get attached to the dynamically added elements or elements which are added after `DOM` load. So you need to attach `event` either to `document` targeting particular `element` in DOM as below:

```
$(document).on('click','.element',function(){
    ...
});
```

or to its parent which was loaded during page load. For Ex:

Say you have below structure:

```
<div class="somediv">
   <!--Many other children elements here-->
</div>
```

Now you will add one more event either by `append` or by `load` or in any other possible ways and structure will become as below:

```
<div class="somediv">
  <!--Many other children elements here-->
  <button class="element">Click here<button> <!--This is dynamically added element -->
</div>
```

and now you can attach event to `.somediv` instead of attaching to `document`, since it was added during `DOM` load and newly added element will be inside this `.somediv`.

> **This will actually improve performance of code as you are explicitly
>   telling `jquery` from where to start to search for the dynamically
>   added `.element` and `jquery` can search it more faster instead of
>   traversing from `document`**

So you can write it as below:

```
$('.somediv').on('click','.element',function(){
 //^^^^parent div         ^^^dynamically added element
    //do anything here
});
```

Comment: Can I do this with addClass and removeClass also? Lastly, can you tell me why what I have doesn't always work? I really want to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Thank you I think this makes sense. I will try it tonight. Can I use multiple $(document) in one javascript file? Also, Does it matter where the delegation goes in the javascript (beginning, middle, end etc.) ...

Comment: @user3174713 You can use multiple `$(document)` to perform `event delegation`..

Comment: This worked. I understand this syntax now. Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me Rao!!!

Comment: Anytime... Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    $("header").load("/_includes/header.html", function () {
       $('.class').click(function () {
           $('#id').slideToggle('fast');
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .live() for older jQuery versions

```
$( ".class" ).live( "click", function() {
  $('#id').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

for older

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: Which is better .live or $(document) ??? Also whats the difference?