# Extra click after dynamically added HTML elements via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

I add some html dynamically in `data.html`

```html
<div class="d-flex " id="deviceSeearchRecords">
  <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 ">
    <button type="button" class="btn deviceName " data-href="@Url.Content(string.Format(" ~/Devices/Details/{0} ", @item.ID))">
        @item.FullName
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

After this I assume to use  click event like this.

```js
$('#searchResultContainer').html('');
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Search", "Devices")', {
    s: $('#searchStr').val()
  },
  function(data) {
    if (data.success === true) {
      $('#searchResultContainer').append(data.html);
      $(document).on('click', '.deviceName', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        // console.log('deviceName ' + $(this).data('href'));
        window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
      });
    }
  });
```

But when I click first time then nothing happens. On second click it works as it should.
I have tried to use `focus()` on `div` but if does not help.

This approach does not help as well [jquery functions inside of dynamically generated html not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354020/jquery-functions-inside-of-dynamically-generated-html-not-working)

What do I missing here?

Comment: you have a missing quote here `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Search", "Devices", { s: $('#searchStr').val() },`

Comment: @Roy Sorry Roy it is not the issue. It exists in the example code only. It has been corrected.

Comment: The click event on .deviceName is registered only after getJSON response is successfully parsed, so it is normal that clicking on that element before the call does nothing.

Comment: Why are you attaching the click event to document inside the asynchronous function?

Comment: @randomSoul I just try to figure out why I need to click twice. Initially I put it outside of async func but iwont work as well.

Comment: All the point of binding dynamic elements is that you can do it outside of the async function. If you want to bind it inside the callback function, you can bind it in the regular way.

Comment: I simulated it myself and it works.  It's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt3kLyr6/)

Comment: @sugars Thanks man. You are right.  It seems it has something to do with Bootstrap 4.3?  Because even if no active elements have been inserted if I do right or left mouse clicks the entire area glimpses like it gets focus.

Comment: @Developer From the code you provide, it seems to be irrelevant to bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all!

I found my solution here
[Is it possible to focus on a <div> using JavaScript focus() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

So I just use a regular `<a>` within  `data.html` and after this `focus` on the `div` with dynamically added data. And one click works!

```
$('#searchResultContainer').html('');
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Search", "Devices")', {
    s: $('#searchStr').val()
  },
  function(data) {
    if (data.success === true) {
       if (data.success === true) {
             $('#searchResultContainer').html(data.html);   
             window.location.hash = '#searchResultContainer';
        }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to the outside

```
$(document).on('click', '.deviceName', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // console.log('deviceName ' + $(this).data('href'));
  window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
});
```

Comment: I did. It does not help ((( And ieven if I use `<a>` in the  dynamically added HTML anyway I have to click twice to take an effect.